# Связи в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть 2 таблицы/класса:

```
public class Message {

    public Message() {
    }

    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "recive_user_id")
    private String ReciveUserId;

    @Column(name = "send_user_id")
    private String SendUserId;

    @Column(name = "contain")
    private String contain;
```

и

```
public class UserProf {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "city")
private String city;

@Column(name = "number")
private int number;
```

Необходимо организовать связь *один к одному*, между:

```
id(UserProf(Primary Key)) и ReciveUserId(Message(FK)) 

id(UserProf(Primaty Key)) и SendUserId(Message(FK))
```

Подскажите, как это можно сделать при помощи аннотаций?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Message {

public Message() {
}

@Column
@GeneratedValue
@Id
private Integer id;

@OneToOne 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn   
@Column(name = "recive_user_id")
private UserProf ReciveUserId;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@Column(name = "send_user_id")
private UserProf SendUserId;

@Column(name = "contain")
private String contain
```

Comment: Хотя лучше вместо @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn использовать @JoinColumn(name = "recive_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")

Comment: в таблице UserProf изменения какие-то вносить нужно?

Comment: Нет, не надо вносить

Comment: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @OneToOne property: com.db.table.Message.ReciveUserId

Comment: Уберите аннотацию @Column, кажется с чем то перепутал

Comment: Помогло, спасибо;)

Comment: Хорошо, прошу прощения за косяк. В полях с внешним ключом эта аннотация не используется.